# Python - Can I sort a list of tuples by object attribute?

Tags: python

Thanks to this site, I know how to sort a list by object attribute, and I know how to sort a list of tuples by value, but I can't seem to manage to sort a list of tuples by object attribute.

Here are the sort methods I would like to combine.

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x.attribute)
list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `list.sort(key=lambda x: (x.attribute,x[1]))` something like this? we'd need some input & expected output...

Comment: `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].attribute)` or `list.sort(key=lambda x: x.attribute[1])` according to your data structure.

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast.  falsetru posted exactly what I wanted.  Thank you both!  I will review example guidelines and do my best to implement in future posts.